# Question on sequence space (as a linear space)

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Let $X$ be the space $\ell_\infty$ of all bounded sequences of real scalars. If $Y$ is the set of all $x\in X$ that have bounded partial sums

(1) Can I say $Y$ is a linear space (as a subspace of $X$), and $Y$ is equal to the range of the operator $L-I$ on $X$, where $L$ is the operator from $s(n)$ to $s(n+1)$ and $I$ the identity map.

(2) If $c=(1,1,1,....)$ the constant sequence of ones, then $\|c-y\|\geq 1$ for any $y\in Y$.

Comment: what is $L$ exactly?

Comment: $L$ is the left shift operator that maps $s(1),s(2),....)$ to $(s(2),s(3),....)$.

Comment: is (1) one of your thought, or something you have to prove ?

Comment: Extract it from something similar, but need the proof. waiting for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (1) :

First you can easily check that for $L-I : X \rightarrow X$, we have $Im(L-I) \subset Y$ because the elements of the image of $L-I$ have the form $(s(2)-s(1),s(3)-s(2),\ldots)$ where $s \in X$ and the sequence of its partial sums is $(s(2)-s(1),s(3)-s(2)+s(2)-s(1)=s(3)-s(1),\ldots,s(n)-s(1),\ldots) = s - s(1).c$ which is clearly in X and hence bounded.

Conversly, Let's define the operator $S$ on $Y$ by :

$S(y(1),y(2),\ldots) = S(0,y(1),y(1) + y(2),\ldots)$ which just transforms a sequence to the sequence of it's partial sum shifted to the right. By definition of $Y$, $S : Y \rightarrow X$.

Now, take $y \in Y$, then $S(y)$ is an antecedent of $y$ for $L-I$, since $(L-I)(S(y)) = (y_1 - 0= y_1,y_2+y_1-y_1=y_2,\ldots)=y$. So all elements of $Y$ are reached by $L-I$ and $Im(L-I)=Y$.

For (2), assume that $||c-y|| = \epsilon < 1$, it means that $\forall n, |y(n) - 1| \leq \epsilon$ and it implies $y(n) \geq 1-\epsilon = \mu > 0$ But then the partial sums can't be bounded anymore, since, $\sum_{i=1}^n y(i) \geq n\mu \to \infty$

edit : for the additionnal question you asked in the comment section :

1) Let's show that $||f|| \leq 1$ : we pick $\lambda c + y \in Y^*$ with $\lambda > 0$, then we apply (2) with $c - \frac{1}{\lambda}y$ and multiply the inequality by $\lambda$, we get $||\lambda c - y|| \geq \lambda$, that we can write $||\lambda c - y|| \geq |f(\lambda c - y)|$. We do the same when $\lambda < 0$ (by applying (2) to $-c - \frac{1}{\lambda}y$ and multiplying by $-\lambda$). Finally, when $\lambda=0$, it's trivially true because $f(0.c + y)=0$. So, we showed that $\forall y^* \in Y^*, ||y^*|| \geq |f(y^*)|$ that is by definition of the norm of $f$, $||f|| \leq 1$.

Now, if we take juste $c=1.c + 0 \in Y^*$, we see that $|f(c)|=||c||=1$ and hence $||f|| \geq 1$.

Finally, $||f||=1$.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. What is $L_s$. One more thing I would like to know if you have time. Suppose that $Y^*$ is the linear subspace that span $Y$ and $c$, and contain all $\alpha c+y$ for some scalar $\alpha$. If we define a linear functional $f$ by $f(\alpha c+y)=\alpha$, prove that $\|f\|=1$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're welcome. I misread the definition of your shift operator (wrong direction), si I corrected the proof and also made it lighter. I'll take a look to your other question when I have time.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will be waiting you.

Comment: I added the anwser to your second question too. Please accept the answer if it seems ok to you :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, surely I will accept it ;)